# Why does show() behave inconsistently in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have inconsistent behaviour from `show` in Julia, depending if it is called explicitly or from the REPL. What is the **one** method I can overload such that I always see the same output?

Specifically, I am defining a new type:

```
immutable Rigid3D{T<:Real}
    rotation::ImmutableArrays.Matrix3x3{T}
    translation::ImmutableArrays.Vector3{T}
end
```

with a show function:

```
import Base.show

function show{T}(io::IO,trans::Rigid3D{T})
    println(io,typeof(trans))
    println(io,"- rotation:")
    println(io,trans.rotation)
    println(io,"- translation:")
    print(io,trans.translation)
end
```

When the REPL displays my function I get a certain type of output for the rotation matrix which looks like

```
RigidTransforms.Rigid3D{Float64}
- rotation:
3x3 ImmutableArrays.Matrix3x3{Float64}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0
- translation:
[0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

while I get what I actually want by explictly calling `show` or `print` or similar:

```
RigidTransforms.Rigid3D{Float64}
- rotation:
[1.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 1.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 1.0]
- translation:
[0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `showarray` / `show` for arrays has some extra-super-special global variable "goodness" thrown in. One can get the output I want by setting some flags explicitly, as in

```
Base.showarray(io,trans.rotation,header=false,repr=true)
```

Follow up question: is this a good way to go about things?

Answer (score 1):

[Section 45.3](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=multimedia#multimedia-i-o) of Julia Doc contains related topics about Multimedia I/O, Refer to this section, the up most api to create output of an object is `display()` function, so anywhere calling `display()` directly could be a way to create the standard output:

```
 julia> r=rand(1:10,3,4)
3x4 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  9  6  10
 10  4  9   3
  2  7  9   3
julia> display(r)
3x4 Array{Int64,2}:
  6   9  10  6
  7  10   3  8
 10   3   1  3
```

The next tire to create output representation of an object is `writemime()` function, normally this function is called by `display()` with suitable `IO` and `MIME` type. (check source : [julia/base/multimedia.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/multimedia.jl))
So another way to create the same output is calling `writemime()`:

```
julia> writemime(STDOUT,"text/plain",r)
3x4 Array{Int64,2}:
  6   9  10  6
  7  10   3  8
 10   3   1  3
```

And the last tire is `show()` function, see how `writemime()` utilizes different implementation of it to create an object representation, [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/replutil.jl).
e.g. The one that is called to output a `"text/plain"` view of `Array` looks like:
`showarray(IOContext(io, :limit_output => true), v, header=true, repr=false)`

```
julia> Base.showarray(STDOUT, r, header=true, repr=false)
3x4 Array{Int64,2}:
  6   9  10  6
  7  10   3  8
 10   3   1  3
```

But as it is visible from the source, `writemime()` use `IOContext` type to customize the output, so the aboves are not exactly the same. To see the difference compare outputs of `rand(Int,4,5)`:

```
julia> r=rand(Int,4,5);

julia> Base.showarray(STDOUT, r, header=true, repr=false);
4x5 Array{Int64,2}:
 -9150711412447851532  -4064307792165254874  -9145005121012096632   877869689862
3596311  -1624484174873216444
 -6072167451473199347   3776198281339796836   2251800342396330066   278057847557
1491665  -3073806755949099776
 -6526051806709869625  -1478837742375450002  -4067570915681650210   818574986937
5316317  -5612815197244826930
  3274244289756062731   2761828107403369455   1969450819804018106  -130408388331
4107544   6697765697249990460
julia> r
4x5 Array{Int64,2}:
 -9150711412447851532  -4064307792165254874  .  -1624484174873216444
 -6072167451473199347   3776198281339796836     -3073806755949099776
 -6526051806709869625  -1478837742375450002     -5612815197244826930
  3274244289756062731   2761828107403369455      6697765697249990460
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `show` is still the correct thing to overload, and indeed you have correctly overloaded `show` for your own type.

What seems to be happening is that `show` is not working correctly (?) for the type from the `ImmutableArrays` package. Since you did not provide working code, I was unable to create an object of your type and test thoroughly.

Note that the package `FixedSizeArrays` is a replacement for `ImmutableArrays` which is now ready for use. Could you test what happens when you use that package instead?